# Вставка элемента с пощью insertBefore

Tags: dom

```
<footer>
  <div class="info">
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
  </div>
</footer>

<script>
    var div = document.createElement('section');
    div.innerHTML = "<b>Секция</b>";
    document.insertBefore(div, document.getElementsByClassName('info'));
</script>
```

Почему в HTML перед элементом с классом (class="info") не вставляется генерируемый контент из JS? В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Вы допустили две ошибки:

1. getElementsByClassName возвращает коллекцию нод, а не одну ноду.
2. insertBefore надо вызывать не у документа, а у родительской ноды того элемента, перед которым вы хотите вставить

```js
var div = document.createElement('section');
div.innerHTML = "<b>Секция</b>";
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('info')[0];
target.parentNode.insertBefore(div, target);
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="info">
    <p>text 1</p>
    <p>text 2</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```